# Average Goals Per Game

Tags: probability

Okay I am trying to work something out. If for example Team A scored an average of 2.84 goals per game over a period of 95 matches. What is the probability that there next match will be 3 goals or over? I'm not sure how hard this is to do or if its even possible. But would love an answer if possible. Thanks

Comment: You can't tell anything from this little data.

Comment: To answer this question you need to know the standard error in your data. Then you can calculate a z statistic for observing 3 goals and use that to approximate the probability.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know (or assume) more about the distribution than just the mean. For example, you might assume a Poisson distribution.  There is some justification for believing this might be a good approximation: it would be the case if all opponents were equivalent and goal-scoring occurred as a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process).  On the other hand, it would not fit very well with e.g. a style of play that becomes very defensive once a lead is obtained.

If we assume a Poisson distribution with mean $2.84$, the probability of $3$ or more in a game would be approximately $0.54$.

Answer (score 0):

To make clearer why we can't know the probability you seek, consider the following: there are many ways a team can get an average score of $2.84$ in $95$ matches.

One way is to score no goals for $94$ matches, and then score all $270$ goals in a single match.

One way is to score three goals per game for ninety matches, and go scoreless the last five.

There are roughly $10^{89}$ other possible goal distributions (if we care about the order), and the true one is probably somewhere in-between, but can you see how these two extremes drastically change the odds of scoring at least three goals in a given game? In the end, the only thing we know is that $270$ goals were scored, we have no data to say anything about any consistency for the team.